# Ext JS 3 Auto Width Column Grid

Tags: javascript, extjs

Excuse me, 
How can I set the autowidth in the grid column on Ext JS 3?
This is my code, so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            Ext.onReady(function () {
                var mystore = new Ext.data.Store({proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({url: 'info-extjs.php'}),
                    reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
                        root: 'guests',
                        fields: [{name: 'ip_address'},
                            {name: 'country'},
                            {name: 'region'},
                            {name: 'comp_name'},
                            {name: 'page'},
                            {name: 'timestamp'}]
                    })
                });
                //create the grid     
                var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
                    store: mystore,
                    title: 'Guest List of our blog',
                    columns: [{
                            id: 'ip_address',
                            header: 'IP Address',
                            autoSizeColumn: true, 
                            minWidth: 120,
                            sortable: true,
                            dataIndex: 'ip_address'
                        },
                        {
                            id: 'country',
                            header: 'Country',
                            autoSizeColumn: true, 
                            minWidth: 120,
                            sortable: true,
                            dataIndex: 'country'
                        },
                        {
                            header: 'region',
                            autoSizeColumn: true, 
                            minWidth: 120,
                            sortable: true,
                            dataIndex: 'region'
                        },
                        {
                            header: 'comp_name',
                            autoSizeColumn: true, 
                            minWidth: 120,
                            sortable: true,
                            dataIndex: 'comp_name'
                        },
                        {
                            header: 'page',
                            sortable: true,
                            dataIndex: 'page',
                            autoSizeColumn: true, 
                            minWidth: 150
                        },
                        {
                            header: 'timestamp',
                            sortable: true,
                            dataIndex: 'timestamp',
                            autoSizeColumn: true, 
                            minWidth: 150
                        }],
                    renderTo: 'guest-list-grid',

                    autoHeight: true
                });
                mystore.load();
            });
        </script>
```

I try to use:

```
autoSizeColumn: true, 
minWidth: 150
```

But, unfortunately, it is not working. This is the picture:
[image: result]
Please help. Ext Js Version:
ext-3.4.0

Comment: Add width to your grid and check once.If it doesnt work you can always show a tooltip on mouse over.

Comment: if we set width, it means not auto width. Is that possible to add width:auto ?

Comment: I am suggesting to add width in pixel and then add overflowX or autoscroll so that you will get the scroll bar .Please check once

Comment: yes, that way is what usually we did, but.. Ext JS 4 has ability to autoresize the column. I am looking the way to make that happened at ext js 3.4. Or maybe statement from anyone, please tell me if this is impossible to do at ext js 3.4 with rational reason, please let me know..

Answer (score 0):

try adding [forceFit: true](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.GridPanel) to grids's viewconfig

```
...
renderTo: 'guest-list-grid',    
viewConfig: {
    forceFit: true
},
```

Comment: the result is like this: Image Link : http://gyazo.com/35fe6c873ca7453e3d93f439355a239a to many spaces.. How, Sir?